# How could i speed up this method

Tags: c#, math, optimization, for-loop, simulation

I`m attempting to implement the iWave water surface simulation outlined in [Simulating ocean water (PDF)](http://www-evasion.imag.fr/people/Fabrice.Neyret/images/fluids-nuages/waves/Jonathan/articlesCG/simulating-ocean-water-01.pdf) there is a code extract at the end.

The particular method is for calculating the vertical derivative using a convolution kernel

```
for(int ix = 6; ix < iwidth - 6; ix++)
{
    for(int iy = 6; iy < iheight - 6; iy++)
    {
        int index = ix + iwidth * iy;
        float vd = 0;

        // apply convolution
        for(int iix = -6; iix <= 6; iix++)
        {
            for(int iiy = -6; iiy <= 6; iiy++)
            {
                int iindex = ix + iix + iwidth * (iy + iiy);
                vd += kernel[iix + 6, iiy + 6] * height[iindex];
            }
        }
        vertical_derivative[index] = vd;
    }
}
```

At every point in height (a flattened 2x2 array) the convolution kernel (2x2 array size 13)
is used to calculate the vertical derivative. 
It becomes too slow for real time interaction when the height grid is sized (128x128) but I would like a larger grid. How could I speed this up?

Comment: http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html

Comment: You could also use a different algorithm, for example instead of calculating the convolution you could use a frequency domain approach using the 2d-FFT.

Comment: I think this belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (I cannot flag it for this)

Comment: could you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

A faster way to carry out the convolution is to make use of the identity FT(conv(f, g)) = FT(f) FT(g), that is, the Fourier transform of the convolution of two functions is the pointwise product of their Fourier transforms. So conv(f, g) = FT^-1 (FT(f) FT(g)) where FT^-1 is the inverse Fourier transform. Use the fast Fourier transform.

Answer (score 1):

I do agree that the highest gain will be obtained using the graphics card in some way.

However, note two approaches:

1. You can move some of the basic arithmetic on the indices out of the innermost loop. 
   This will give you about 10% speedup. This is worth doing in addition to whatever threading you use.
2. Just use the `Parallel.For` built in language feature; this will parallelise on the CPU and is very easy to use.

   ```
       const int convolutionWidth = 6;
       Parallel.For(convolutionWidth, iwidth - convolutionWidth, ix =>
       {
           for (int iy = convolutionWidth; iy < iheight - convolutionWidth; iy++)
           {
               int index = ix + iwidth * iy;
               float vd = 0;
               // apply convolution
               for (int iix = -convolutionWidth; iix <= convolutionWidth; iix++)
               {
                   int iindex = ix + iix + iwidth * (iy - convolutionWidth);
                   for (int iiy = -convolutionWidth; iiy <= convolutionWidth; iiy++)
                   {
                       vd += kernel[iix + convolutionWidth, iiy + convolutionWidth] * height[iindex];
                       iindex += iwidth;
                   }
               }
               vertical_derivative[index] = vd;
           }
       });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of scenario is highly optimizable using SIMD capabilities (if your hardware supports it).

However, CLR does not use full SIMD capabilities as of today. For an experimental use, you can download [RyuJit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/09/30/ryujit-the-next-generation-jit-compiler.aspx), which supports it [(see this link for more info)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/04/07/the-jit-finally-proposed-jit-and-simd-are-getting-married.aspx)

The main idea would be to refactor a bit your data format in order to use vectors for your operations (instead of just numbers)

Speed ups can be quite impressive (up to x6 depending on your hardware).

Comment: True, but running in on graphics hardware is much better.